# Why does Varys board the Ship to Essos?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of episode 10 of Game of Throne's season 4

> Tyrion Lannister kills his former lover Shae and his father Tywin Lannister.

Why

> does Varys, who helped Tyrion to escape, join him when he heard the bells from the castle, which implied that someone (important) had died. Varys did not support any murder, all he knew was, that he shall help Tyrion to escape so he would not be found guilty and eventually executed. Especially not, because Jamie would not give him away, as that would mean that Jamie would have been guilty as well.

Comment: The title is still fairly rubbish, but I tried to avoid including a spoiler -- to a nearly two year old episode, so perhaps I shouldn't bother.

Comment: Certainly right, but I feel like that the finale of a season might need some proper spoiler in any case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because returning to his job could be [unsafe](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Children):

> Tyrion discards the crossbow as he leaves to find Varys, who
>   immediately realizes Tyrion has done something terrible, exclaiming
>   "What have you done?" Nonetheless, he leads Tyrion out of the castle
>   to the docks where Tyrion is stowed away inconspicuously in a crate
>   aboard the ship. **Varys begins walking back towards the Red Keep but
>   stops when he hears the bells begin to toll, signaling the discovery
>   of Tywin's body. Realizing that returning to the castle is likely
>   unsafe, Varys turns around and heads back for the ship**, sitting next
>   to Tyrion's crate in silence as they cast off for Essos.

Comment: +1. Cersei will be looking for someone to blame for her father's death, and she has never liked or trusted Varys. It is prudent for Varys to be far away from Cersei's rage.

Comment: And given that Varys did indeed effect Tyrion’s escape, the risk of someone finding that out suddenly became the risk of being executed for assisting in the murder of The Hand of the King. Stakes done changed.

Answer (score 0):

Upon hearing the sound of the bells ringing, Varys immediately realizes that he is now trapped outside the city's walls, as either the King's Guard has discovered Tyrion's escape, or someone has found Tywin and Shae murdered. Either way, he knows The Red Keep and the city will be locked down and he will be easily implicated as a co-conspirator once discovered outside the walls in the middle of the night, leaving him no choice but to flee with Tyrion.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SciFi.SE!   Why is he trapped?  He was traveling quite freely through secret passageways....

Comment: This is basically the same explanation as [the one provided by BCdotWEB back in 2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/125403/122024). There's not much point in posting a new answer to an old question if you have nothing new to add.